# Facebook graph API {post-id}/likes returns empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This request returns an empty array: `graph.facebook.com/773227196065108/likes`, but this  request returns a normal array: `graph.facebook.com/576234822476425/likes`.

First post - post from user, second post - post from page.

How do I get a normal result in the first case?

Answer (score 0):

http://graph.facebook.com/773227196065108 returns

```
{
   error: {
   message: "An access token is required to request this resource.",
   type: "OAuthException",
   code: 104
   }
}
```

since its a user post and probably not public, **you will have to access it using a proper access token** on behalf of the user . also the number of likes obtained via graph api is dependant on the the privacy settings of people who liked the post .

the second post is one from a page and is public, so its directly accessible for you .

Comment: I liked this post: [link](https://www.facebook.com/alshevchenko/posts/773227196065108)  
Then run this code:&nbsp;&nbsp;
`$fb_query = new FacebookRequest($fb_session, 'GET', '/me/likes/773227196065108');
        $fb_response = $fb_query->execute();
        $fb_graphObj = $fb_response->getGraphObject();
        
        var_dump($fb_graphObj);`  
And get this result:  
`object(Facebook\GraphObject)#6 (1) { ["backingData":protected]=> array(0) { } }`  
I have user_likes permission and post is available to all users.

Answer (score 0):

`773227196065108` is a user whereas `576234822476425` is a page. Public page posts can be inspected in the API, public user posts have certain restrictions applied to them such as, the queried user must be using the application as well. If the queried user isn't using the querying application the response will be empty.

In addition `/me/likes/773227196065108` will not work as `/me/likes` are only for pages not posts.

Comment: So how can I know if a user (/me) liked a post or not?