# Facebook graph API /me/likes returns are not all my likes

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Facebook graph API /me/likes returns are not all my likes.
After the query `/me/likes` does not return all the posts that I liked.
Query return:
`{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Engineering/construction", 
      "name": "КИРИЛЛ кирпич и черепица", 
      "created_time": "2015-01-10T17:47:29+0000", 
      "id": "1478075375788767"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Science website", 
      "name": "Science", 
      "created_time": "2015-01-06T20:22:14+0000", 
      "id": "130228610410384"
    }, 
    ...
}`
But that's not all the posts, which I Liked.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/me/likes` only returns pages you like. Not posts.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes

> The Facebook Pages that this person has 'liked'.

Comment: Can I look with graph API posts that I liked?

Comment: @IgorKvilinsky rephrase your question.

Comment: Sorry for my English. Can I see posts which I liked by graph API?

Comment: @IgorKvilinsky no sorry this isn't possible. I've explained the reasoning in your next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882138/facebook-graph-api-post-id-likes-returns-empty-data